# Can we write Cython 'cdef' functions and use them outside of cython?

Tags: python, cython, cythonize, uvloop

It is known for a while that Cython is a great way to improve pythons' speed. In addition, few efficient libraries use Cython to do so.

One of them is called 'uvloop'. However, when I looked at their source code, I saw that most of it uses the "cdef" keyword - which I think means that you can't access the code from python-only code.

I'm Almost for sure that 'uvloop' it is accessible from pure python code, so what is going on? It is possible or not to build a library that would be accessible for python clients and it's even worth it?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use cdef directly from python, but you could use the functionality through wrappers (for example cpdef-functions).

Comment: So how uvloop uses it?